# Usage of "even if temporarily"

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to say the following sentence?

> By drinking, I am trying to forget things, even if temporarily.

Or I should put it inside parenthesis? Like

> By drinking, I am trying to forget things (even if temporarily).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any parenthesis. The sentence by itself is correct.

> By drinking, I am trying to forget things, even if temporarily.

**Even if -**

Used for emphasizing that although something may happen or may be true, another situation remains the same

**Example -**

> *He's determined to prove his innocence, **even if** he has to go to the highest court in the land.*